# Cython: How to move large objects without copying them?

Tags: c++, python, memory-management, cython

I use Cython to wrap C++ code and expose it to Python for interactive work. My problem is that I need to read large graphs (several gigabytes) from file and they end up twice in the memory. Can anyone help me diagnose and solve this problem?

My Cython wrapper for the graph class looks like this:

```
cdef extern from "../src/graph/Graph.h":
    cdef cppclass _Graph "Graph":
        _Graph() except +
        _Graph(count) except +
        count numberOfNodes() except +
        count numberOfEdges() except +


cdef class Graph:
    """An undirected, optionally weighted graph"""
    cdef _Graph _this

    def __cinit__(self, n=None):
        if n is not None:
            self._this = _Graph(n)

    # any _thisect which appears as a return type needs to implement setThis
    cdef setThis(self, _Graph other):
        #del self._this
        self._this = other
        return self

    def numberOfNodes(self):
        return self._this.numberOfNodes()

    def numberOfEdges(self):
        return self._this.numberOfEdges()
```

If a Python Graph needs to be returned, it needs to be created empty and then the `setThis` method is used to set the native `_Graph` instance. This happens, for example, when a `Graph` is read from file. This is the job of this class:

```
cdef extern from "../src/io/METISGraphReader.h":
    cdef cppclass _METISGraphReader "METISGraphReader":
        _METISGraphReader() except +
        _Graph read(string path) except +

cdef class METISGraphReader:
    """ Reads the METIS adjacency file format [1]
        [1]: http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/metis_graph/metis_graph.html
    """
    cdef _METISGraphReader _this

    def read(self, path):
        pathbytes = path.encode("utf-8") # string needs to be converted to bytes, which are coerced to std::string
        return Graph(0).setThis(self._this.read(pathbytes))
```

Interactive usage looks like this:

```
 >>> G = graphio.METISGraphReader().read("giant.metis.graph")
```

After the reading from file is done and X GB memory are used, there is a phase where obviously copying happens, and after that 2X GB memory are used. The entire memory is freed when `del G` is called.

Where is my error which leads to the graph being copied and existing twice in memory?

Comment: I think this question of mine is somehow related, it describes a similar problem: '[Providing python proxy objects for C++ class instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108204/providing-python-proxy-objects-for-c-class-instances)'. My idea was to wrap smart pointers, I'd say going forward to movable unique instances should be similar.

Comment: Can you show the definition of class `_Graph`? In particular, the constructor(s), copy constructor and destructor. Also, it's odd to see that `_this` is an object and not a pointer to an object. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Miguel: Here is the header: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7624793
Pointers practically do not appear in the in the C++ source, objects are stack-allocated and returned by value (relying on copy elision and move semantics for large objects - perhaps this does not work?). Would it work to make `_this` a pointer if the C++ methods which create graphs return by value?

Comment: Just confirmed that the copying only happens when using the class via Python.

Comment: Can you also show the implementation of `METISGrahReader::read`?

Comment: @Miguel Sure, here you go: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7630790 What are you looking for?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to reproduce this problem and I can't, so I'm looking for other potential places where the extra obj can be. I do see the copies (this is actually expected since you are passing objects around instead of pointers to them), but I always end up with one object left, not two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a definitive answer for you, but I have a theory.

The Cython wrappers that you wrote are unusual, in that they wrap the C++ object directly instead of a pointer to it.

The following code is particularly inefficient:

```
cdef setThis(self, _Graph other):
    self._this = other
    return self
```

The reason is that your `_Graph` class contains several STL vectors, and those will have to be copied over. So, when your `other` object is assigned to `self._this` the memory usage is effectively doubled (or worse, since the STL allocators can overallocate for performance reasons).

I wrote a simple test that matches yours and added logging everywhere to see how objects are created, copied or destroyed. I can't find any issues there. The copies do happen, but after the assignment is complete I see that only one object remains.

So my theory is that the extra memory that you see is related to STL allocator logic in the vectors. All that extra memory must be attached to the final object after the copies.

My recommendation is that you switch to the more standard pointer based wrapping. Your `_Graph` wrapper then should be defined more or less as follows:

```
cdef class Graph:
    """An undirected, optionally weighted graph"""
    cdef _Graph* _this

    def __cinit__(self, n=None):
        if n is not None:
            self._this = new _Graph(n)
        else:
            self._this = 0

    cdef setThis(self, _Graph* other):
        del self._this
        self._this = other
        return self

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self._this
```

Note that I need to delete `_this` because it is a pointer.

You will then need to modify your `METISGraphReader::read()` method to return a heap allocated `Graph`. The prototype of this method should be changed to:

```
Graph* METISGraphReader::read(std::string path);
```

Then the Cython wrapper for it can be written as:

```
    def read(self, path):
        pathbytes = path.encode("utf-8") # string needs to be converted to bytes, which are coerced to std::string
        return Graph().setThis(self._this.read(pathbytes))
```

If you do it this way there is only one object, the one that is created on the heap by `read()`. A pointer to that object is returned to the `read()` Cython wrapper, which then installs it in a brand new `Graph()` instance. The only thing that gets copied is the 4 or 8 bytes of the pointer.

I hope this helps!

Comment: In C++11, a copy does not necessarily happen just because one passes objects around, e.g. [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) and [move semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Move_semantics#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors). So if I understand you correctly, this is not applicable to my Cython code and an assignment implies a copy, right?

Comment: These are just compiler optimizations not strict rules, correct?. A smart compiler may detect that a move is sufficient, a not so smart compiler may not and do copies. You have to agree that the object makes a few trips until it lands where it needs to go, the object is created in the C++ `read()`, then returned to the Cython `read()`, which passes it by value to `setThis()`, which assigns it to another object. You aren't making it any easy for the compiler. In case it matters, I tested this with gcc 4.7.3, the data gets copied once, and three or four brand new objects were created/destroyed.

Comment: That makes sense, and so does your proposed solution. I will test and report.

Comment: I tried it and it works. The copy is gone, thanks. Is it normal that the memory used by the Python process as seen in `top` does not drop when `del G` is called? `del G` or reusing the variable seems to free the memory though.

Comment: Python's memory management is not as predictable as in C++ because objects get deleted through garbage collection, which may occur some time after the object is deleted. Something you can do to check when the C++ object goes away is to add a printf inside the `__dealloc__` method, at least that will help confirm that the object is not leaked.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to modify the C++ class to store it's data via a shared_ptr.
Make sure you have a proper copy constructor and assignment operator:

```
#define  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>

struct Data { // your graph data
    Data(const char* _d = NULL) {
        if (_d)
            strncpy(d, _d, sizeof(d)-1);
        else
            memset(d, 0, sizeof(d));
    }
    Data(const Data& rhs) {
        memcpy(d, rhs.d, sizeof(d));
    }
    ~Data() {
        memset(d, 0, sizeof(d));
    }
    void DoSomething() { /* do something */ } // a public method that was used in Python

    char d[1024];
};

class A { // the wrapper class
public:
    A() {}
    A(const char* name)  : pData(new Data(name)) {}
    A(const A& rhs) : pData(rhs.pData) {}
    A& operator=(const A& rhs) {
        pData = rhs.pData;
        return *this;
    }
    ~A() {}
    // interface with Data
    void DoSomething() {
        if (pData.get() != NULL)
            pData->DoSomething();
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Data> pData;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    A o1("Hello!");
    A o2(o1);
    A o3;
    o3 = o2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since this would be a major change in the implementation, can you explain why the copying/duplication takes place when the class is used via Cython, why not when it is used via C++ only, and why a shared pointer would help?

Comment: A shared pointer takes care of the cleanup - when no object references the data. It also takes care of the reference counting for you. The behavior you described of Cython performing a full copy of the returned object means that either copy constructor (most likely) or an assignment operator is used to create a copy of the outer C++ object. Wrapping (proxy) that C++ leaves you Python code intact. All that's left for you is to expose all the public (used) methods of the inner object so Python thinks it interfaces with the lower level object. I'll add a method in Data to show this.

Comment: I'd rather leave my C++ code mostly intact, because what you propose is quite a radical change to the most used class of the project, but I will consider your solution.

Answer (score -3):

If your constraint/goal is **“Compute on graphs with billions of edges, in a reasonable time, on a single PC.”**, consider refactoring to leverage [GraphChi](http://strata.oreilly.com/2012/12/graphchi-graph-analytics-over-billions-of-edges-using-your-laptop.html).

If single-machine/in-memory is not a constraint, consider leveraging a graph database like [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/) instead of pulling all data into memory.  There are also graph APIs that overlay with Hadoop (e.g. [Apache Giraph](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5Qmz4zPj-M)).

Comment: I am not looking for an alternative graph framework, but working on the long-term project of building one.

Comment: I didn't see that called out in you original post.  Good luck on your framework.